# Estimate gas for mint function on contract without any eth in a wallet (ethers)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethers.js

I'm trying to estimate the gas to call a mint function on some contracts, but most of them require you to pass an eth value or else they will fail. However the wallet I am using contains no eth, so if I try:
`let mintFee = await contract.estimateGas.mint(1, {"value": ethers.utils.parseEther("1")});`, I get: `Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost`. Does anyone know how to call the mint function without having any eth in a wallet?